# Numpy array of specified number of 1s and 0s in order

Tags: python, numpy

Expected Output: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

My method:

```
out = [1]*len(positive)
out.extend([0]*len(negative))
out = np.array(out)
```

I feel there should be a better way to generate a numpy array like this, instead of this three step process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> np.repeat([1, 0], [4, 2])
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

The first argument is an array-like whose elements will be repeated.  The second argument specifies the number of repeats, elementwise.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think your solution is fine. No need to over complicate things. Of course, you can make it more neat with `+` notation:

```
out = np.array([1]*4 + [0]*2)
```

gives ...

```
[1 1 1 1 0 0]
```